# mount_smbfs ignores default file and directory permissions

Tags: samba, mount

I mount the remote folder on my MacOS client with:

```
mount_smbfs -d 0774 -f 0774 //user@192.168.128.48/NAS /Volumes/NAS
```

However, newly created files are still created with the default UNIX permissions. 744 for files and 755 for directories.

The permissions I specified with -d and -f seem to be ignored?

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would likely be because the mount options change the apparent permissions on the local files, not the remote file's permissions. By mounting with -d 0774 -f 0774, all mounted files will locally appear to have permissions:

```
-rwxrwxr-- mnt/blah
```

From the server's perspective though, they will have whatever permissions are normally assigned to the file:

```
-rwxr--r-- blah
```

This is usually determined by combination of inherited permissions from the parent, the share's force create mode setting, the share's create mask, and the user's umask.

In short, you probably want to change the configuration on the server side, not the client side.